# Replacing cell with data found in a different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the cell 'Output' to show datatype that is found in cell A.
For example , i am comparing cell C with Cell A , if cell C matches cell A , cell B data will be displayed on output column . is this achievable  ?

The closes i tried is by using `=countif(cellA1:cellA5,CellC1) > 0` but this will only return true or false. im trying to acheive the datatype on output column

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `VLookup()` like-

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$1:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

You can also use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination like-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0))
```

If you have `Office365` then you can use `XLOOKUP()` single function like-

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$6)
```

[image]